# ARCore geospatial - how to get geospatial position from a saved anchor

Tags: android, geospatial, arcore

I'm playing with the new ARcore cloud anchor with geospatial API. I was following the [google codelab](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/geospatial/codelab#0) to understand how it works, but I can't get the geospatial coordinates after the anchor is saved.
When I create the anchor the code is like this:

```
earth.createAnchor(cameraGeospatialPose.latitude, cameraGeospatialPose.longitude, altitude, currentAnchor!!.pose.qx(), currentAnchor!!.pose.qy(), currentAnchor!!.pose.qz(), currentAnchor!!.pose.qw())
```

but, when the `onHostedAnchorAvailable(anchor: Anchor)` is called, I can get the pose data, but I can't get the geospatial pose data. It seems the GET geospatial pose method is missing. The only workaround, is to save the geospatial position in a global data structure, and connect that data with the anchor saved and provided by `onHostedAnchorAvailable`. But it seems horrible and not the correct way to do it.
Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: The main porpose is to create an anchor and save it. in order to let other users see that anchor.
it seems that the anchor I get back from the SDK api after I save it (by its callback), has a different position.
If I use the anchor get back from the api, I can see the green droid in the same position like my phone, instead of where I put it before to save it.
This is the [repo](https://github.com/wiulma/arcoresample) to test the issue
Is there anyone could point me to the right direction?

Comment: it seems I was wrong about how to get the correct current geospatial position. I was using the camera position instead of the anchor geospatial position. this is the correct version:  
`val geospatialPose: GeospatialPose = earth.getGeospatialPose(currentAnchor!!.pose)   


var earthAnchor =
                earth.createAnchor(geospatialPose.latitude, geospatialPose.longitude, geospatialPose.altitude, geospatialPose.eastUpSouthQuaternion)`